# SQLAlchemy doesn't map reflected class

Tags: python, reflection, sqlalchemy

I have this code:

```
def advertiser_table(engine):
    return Table('advertiser', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

And later I try this:

```
advertisers = advertiser_table(engine)
...
session.bulk_insert_mappings(
        advertisers.name,
        missing_advetisers.to_dict('records'),
    )
```

where `missing_adverisers` is a Pandas `DataFrame` (but it's not important for this question).

The error this gives me is:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class ''advertiser'' is not mapped
```

From reading the documentation I could scramble enough to ask the question, but not much more than that...  What is `Mapper` and why is it so detrimental to the functioning of this library?..  Why isn't "the class" mapped?  Obviously, what am I to do to "map" it to whatever this library wants it to map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Mapper` is the M in ORM. It is the thing that maps your table (`advertisers` in this case) to instances of a class (which you are missing in this case) in order for you to operate on it.

The reason it's confusing for you is because SQLAlchemy is actually two libraries in one -- one is called SQLAlchemy Core, and the other is the SQLAlchemy ORM. Core provides the ability to work with tables and to construct queries that return *rows*, while the ORM builds on top of Core to provide the ability to work with instances of classes and their relationships as an abstraction. Core roughly corresponds to things you can do on `Connection` and `Engine`, while ORM roughly corresponds to things you can do on `Session`.

So, all of that is to say, `session.bulk_insert_mappings` is an ORM functionality, and you cannot use it without having a mapped class.

What can you do instead? Use the equivalent Core functionality:

```
query = advertisers.insert().values(missing_advetisers.to_dict('records'))
engine.execute(query)  # or session.execute(query)
```

Or even use the pandas-provided [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) function:

```
missing_advetisers.to_sql("advertiser", engine, if_exists="append")
```

If you insist on using the ORM, you need to declare a mapped class for your table. The easiest way when using reflection is to use [`automap`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html). The linked documentation has many examples, so I won't go into detail here.

Comment: Sorry, if you red my previous comment: I forgot the "execute" part. It's all good now.